# Is it possible to import history from a svn checkout to a new git repository?

Tags: git, svn

I have a checkout from an svn repository, the host of which I no longer have access to.  I would like to import this codebase into a new git repository, but I haven't been able to figure out how to import the history rather than just add the files.

Is it possible to import this history from an svn checkout into a new git repository, and if so how would I do this?

Comment: You can use git-svn to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your svn checkout has none of the history locally, that's located on the SVN server.  Without access to the server, all you've got is the versions of the files in your checkout.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.  Thanks for this.

Comment: I'm not sure that I could get that, but if I could what would a 'dump' entail (more specifically, what are the commands to get one)?  Related: why is it that svn checkouts do not include the history?  Or am I just biased because I'm using dvcs?

Comment: I know it isn't a DVCS, I was referring to my use of git, not to my (prior) use of svn.  Thanks for your help!